# error when running OPENROWSET query - what to do with the FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE

Tags: query, azure-vm, openrowset, azure-blob-storage

I want to run a query from Sql server to Blob Storage all in the same Azure Tenant.
my environment :
SQL SERVER 2022 (running on a azure virtual machine)
Blob storage.

I've ran this scripts (some credentials are masked by me)

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL dbageneral 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
     SECRET = 'sv=***';
```

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE dbageneralBlob
WITH (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://dba****.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = dbageneral
);
```

when running this script i get an error:
Msg 4860, Level 16, State 3, Line 15
Cannot bulk load. The file "datatest/users-for-load-test1.fmt" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'datatest/users-for-load-test1.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'dbageneralBlob',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE = 'datatest/users-for-load-test1.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'dbageneralBlob'
) AS DataFile;
```

when i ran this script by BULK INSERT it's ok

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    GCID nvarchar(4000),
    [Currency ISON] nvarchar(4000)
)

BULK INSERT #test
FROM 'datatest/users-for-load-test1.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'dbageneralBlob', FORMAT = 'CSV');

select *
from #test
```

how do i run it from OPENROWSET?
what am i doing wrong?